# sankey image not visualized in powerBI by R script

Tags: r, powerbi

1. I have below sample csv data.

   date,Data Center,Customer,companyID,source,target,value
   6/1/2021,dcA,customer1,companyID1,step1:open_list_view,exit,1
   6/1/2021,dcB,customer2,companyID2,step1:open_list_view,exit,1
   6/1/2021,dcC,customer3,companyID3,step1:open_list_view,exit,1
   6/2/2021,dcD,customer4,companyID4,step1:open_list_view,exit,2
   6/2/2021,dcE,customer5,companyID5,step1:open_list_view,step2:switch_display_option,1
   .....
2. Now I click 'R' icon and then enable R
3. Next I import the csv data to powerBI and drag and drop 'source', 'target' and 'value' columns to "Visualization->Values" section.
4. Then I run below R script, and want to visualize the sankey chart in PowerBI

> ```
> # The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as a preamble for your script: 
> # dataset <- data.frame(source, target, value)
> # dataset <- unique(dataset)
> # Paste or type your script code here:
> library(networkD3)
> node_names <- unique(c(dataset$source, dataset$targe))
> nodes <- data.frame(name=node_names)
> links <- data.frame(source = match(dataset$source, node_names) - 1,
>                     target = match(dataset$target, node_names) - 1,
>                     value = dataset$value)
> sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, 
>               Source = "source",
>               Target = "target",
>               Value = "value")
> ```

5. but i got 'No image was created'.
   [image]

how to correct the code to make the sankey chart can visualized in powerBI?

Comment: Not familiar with this package, but it looks like you have a typo: `node_names <- unique(c(dataset$source, dataset$targe))`. Looks like it should be target. Does your script produce a plot in R? A good place to start would be running the code in R and trying to produce the plot in there.

Comment: sankeyNetwork does not output a plot, it outputs an htmlwidget

Answer (score 0):

every Python and R visuals is plot. it requires the script to be plotted. add R script at end of your code.
something like

```
plot(source, target, type="n",)
```